# How to reduce repeated code in my lists of elements to hide (Java/webDriver)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm running a method in my Java Selenium test suite that hides dynamic elements from a web page (such as location based phone numbers), so that when I later perform a screenshot comparison - it won't fail because of these.

I'm trying to reduce the repeated sections of code in this method. I'm using findElements which returns all instances of an element each time, so then I 'for loop' through each one to hide it. I'm calling the same JavaScript command each time however - so I thought maybe there was a way to do this much neater - but I'm struggling to do so. The bits that change are the variable name for the element(s) and the method of finding it via Selenium. Hopefully that makes sense!

My code is:

```
    private void hideDynamicElements() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    List<WebElement> dynamicTelephoneNumbers = driver.findElements(By.className("telephone-number"));
    for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicTelephoneNumbers){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }

    List<WebElement> dynamicChatWindow = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#chatContainer"));
    for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicChatWindow){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }

    List<WebElement> dynamicDemoChat = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#demoFormChat"));
    for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicDemoChat){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }

    List<WebElement> dynamicDemoChatCTA = driver.findElements(By.className("reach-out"));
    for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicDemoChatCTA){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }

    List<WebElement> dynamicBlogHeader = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.cf.article-header"));
    for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicBlogHeader){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }

    List<WebElement> dynamicBlogFeed = driver.findElements(By.className("js-blog-feed-container"));
    for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicBlogFeed){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); //Wait to be sure all elements have disappeared in the browser
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to reduce the code is to identify responsibilities in the method, such as:

- find resources to be hidden (either by class name or by css selector)
- hide targetted resources

Then, modularize the code according its purpose:

```
private void hideDynamicElements() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
   List<By> criteria = Arrays.asList(
        By.className("telephone-number"),
        By.cssSelector("#chatContainer"),
        By.cssSelector("#demoFormChat"),
        By.className("reach-out"),
        By.cssSelector("div.cf.article-header"),
        By.className("js-blog-feed-container")
   );

   for(By crit : criteria) {
        List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(crit);

        hideElements(elements);
   }
}

private void hideElements(List<WebElement> elements) {
    for (WebElement hideElement : elements){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }
}
```

This approach also minimizes the changes in the code in case you want to:
 - change how elements are hidden, or 
 - hide elements under other classes

Answer (score 2):

Create a function like:-

```
  void visiblity(String Classname, Element hideElement)
    {
        List<WebElement> dynamicBlogFeed = driver.findElements(By.className(Classname));
        for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicBlogFeed){
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
    }
```

Call this fucntion again and again whenever you need it.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

First, initialize an ArrayList as following:

```
     ArrayList<By> dynamicElements = new ArrayList<By>(Arrays.asList((By.className("telephone-number"), By.cssSelector("#demoFormChat"),...,))
```

Then loop through your dynamicElements in the outer loop; in the inner loop you will do your actual tasks.

```
   for(By element: dynamicElements){
        ArrayList<WebElement> dynamicWebElements = driver.findElements(element);
        for (WebElement hideElement : dynamicWebElements){
            ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.visibility='hidden'", hideElement);
        }
   }
```

Hope that it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I would get all the targeted elements with a single CSS selector and hide them with a single JavaScript call. It would be easier to maintain and much faster:

```java
private void hideDynamicElements() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String selectors = ".telephone-number, #chatContainer, #demoFormChat, .reach-out, div.cf.article-header, .js-blog-feed-container";

    String JS_HIDE_CSS_SELECTORS = 
      "var hide = function(element){ element.style.visibility = 'hidden' }; " +
      "var elements = document.querySelectorAll(arguments[0]);              " +
      "Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, hide);                        " ;

    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(JS_HIDE_CSS_SELECTORS, selectors);

    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1); //Wait to be sure all elements have disappeared in the browser
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks! Good idea. Will have a look at using CSS selector for all.